# CodeMirror - Natural line break not displayed

Tags: php, line-breaks, codemirror

First time using CodeMirror and not quite sure how to approach this, consulted the manual but surprisingly could not find anything regarding this particular issue.

I am running a PHP script that generates pairs of `'keys'` and `labels` in a `key ==> label` format, which I then want to display in the CodeMirror area. Now, the output uses natural line breaks (pressing enter) instead of any `<br>` or `\n`, and so far I have not found any way for CodeMirror to recognise those line breaks.

So, what to do? Not really keen on changing up my whole code and place linebreaks everywhere just to satisfy the CodeMirror. Any suggestions are much appreciated.

PHP Output:

```
<?php

$superAdmin = isSuperAdmin();
return [

    'failed' => 'These credentials do not match our records.',
    'throttle' => 'Too many login attempts. Please try again in :seconds seconds.',

]

?>
```

CodeMirror Output:

```
<table id="table_content"><tbody><tr><td><?php<br><br>$superAdmin = isSuperAdmin();<br>return [<br><br>    'failed' => 'These credentials do not match our records.',<br>    'throttle' => 'Too many login attempts. Please try again in :seconds seconds.',<br><br>]<br><br>?></td></tr></tbody></table>
```